# PHP YII : HOW TO UPLOAD VIDEO

Tags: yii

my model code:

```
      public $image;

      return array(
        array('filename', 'required'),
        array('image', 'file', 'types'=>''),
        array('filename', 'length', 'max'=>11),
        array('id, filename', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
```

my view code:

```
     <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image'); ?>
```

my controller code:

```
     $model =  new TblUpload;
     $model->attributes=$_POST['TblUpload'];
     $img = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
     if($img->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/'.$img))
            {       
                $model->filename = $img;
                $model->save(false);
            }
     }
    $this->render('uploadfile',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

hi friends using this code i am able to upload all types of files like images and documents, but i am unable to upload videos.... i have changed my php.ini file max_upload_size also...

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i dont get any error,... the video file just doesnt get uploaded...

Answer (score 0):

In your form view, have you set the enctype for the form?

```
$form = $this->beginWidget(
    'CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'my-form',
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ),
    )
);
```

It could also possibly be the path to the folder you are trying to upload to doesn't exists or is incorrect. Try using getcwd(), eg:

```
$model->my_image->saveAs(getcwd()."/uploads/myfile.jpg");
```

This is most likely the problem, your path in your code above is:

```
 if($img->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/'.$img))
```

The basepath and followed by the ../ probably wrong unless you areally are trying to upload in the directory before your root?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i sorted out how to upload images... 
Here is my controller code.....

public function actionUploadfile()

```
{
        $model =  new TblUpload;    
        if(isset($_POST['TblUpload']))
        {           
            $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($model->save())
            {
            $model->image->saveAs('/wamp/www/fileupload/images/'.$fileName);
            }*/
            $model->attributes=$_POST['TblUpload'];
            $img = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
            if($img->saveAs(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/'.$img))
            {

                $model->filename = $img;
                $model->save(false);
            }   
        }
    $this->render('uploadfile',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

this was the place i got mistaken... but now i am using uploadify extension to upload all kinds of files and edited it to be used for multiple upload at a time

Comment: Please as you already answered your post , mark your response as Answer. as your question labeled with not answered